# Can someone explain why the conditional operator and the assignment operator behave strangely when used together?

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, assignment-operator, conditional-operator

Can someone explain why the below code will not give an error:

```
var x;
false ? null : x = 1;
```

According to [MDN-operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) has a higher operator precedence than the [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), 
which means that the above code should give an error because it's actually parsed like:

```
var x;
(false ? null : x) = 1
```

but it didn't give an error whereas this works as expected:

```
var x;
x = 1 ? alert(x) : null;
```

The above code is parsed like:

```
var x;
x = (1 ? alert(x) : null);
```

because the conditional operator has a higher precedence, but why in my very first code will it not give an error if the conditional operator has a higher precedence than the assignment operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the actual grammar, the two "branches" of the conditional operator are *assignment expressions*. Thus,

```
false ? null : x = 1;
```

is parsed as

```
false ? (null) : (x = 1);
```

Because the *first* expression in a `? :` construct is a *short-circuit expression* in the grammar, the expression

```
x = 1 ? alert(x) : null;
```

is parsed as

```
x = (1 ? alert(x) : null);
```

Comment: So the 2 branches of the conditional operator is not affected by operator precedence if they are assignment operations right whereas if the first operand of the conditional operator is an expression maybe `assignment` or any other its is affected by operator precedence right

Comment: Well, everything in the expression grammar is "affected" by operator precedence; it's the core of the grammar. To parse a conditional expression, the parser accepts a short-circuit logical expression, then the `?`, then an assignment expression, then `:`, then another assignment expression. Of course, all of those expressions can by much simpler.

Comment: but if any of the 2 branches of the conditional operator has an assignment expression its not affected by operator precedence like in the above code only the first operand of the conditional operator is affected

Comment: Really it's the `?` that should be thought of as having higher precedence. That's why your second expression works the way it does. Once the parser has seen that a conditional expression is present by accepting the `?`, it can accept the *lower* precedence assignment expressions with the `:` separator because the grammar makes that unambiguous.

Comment: what about `true ? 5, 7 : null` which gives an error it will not give any error if the 2 braches of the **conditional operator** is having an **assignment expression**

Comment: A comma expression is *not* an assignment expression; it's a lower-precedence production.

Comment: true so this affects only the `Assignment operator` in javascript right

Comment: Yes, that's right. It makes `? :` work out to be very useful in JavaScript, once you get used to it.

Comment: why the first operand of the `conditional` operator is called the `ShortCircuitExpression` in [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-conditional-operator)

Comment: Those names are basically how the grammar represents operator precedence. A *short-circuit expression* is an expression that can involve `&&` and `||` operators.  That makes sense, because the expression to the left of the `?` is a logical test to see which branch of the `? :` to perform.

Comment: that makes sense thank you very much. i was searching for **Operator Precedence** and  **Operator Associativity** through out the *ECMAScript* specification which i didnt find

Answer (score -1):

Because the conditional operator has a higher precedence than the assignment operator your first block is essentially

```js
var x;
(false ? null : x ) = 1;
```

and `(false ? null : x )` becomes `x` so the whole block becomes

```js
var x;
x = 1;
```

if it were `(true ? null : x )` then the second line would equate to `null = 1` which is not correct syntax but an error won't be thrown I believe.

Comment: That's demonstrably incorrect — https://jsbin.com/modugojidu/edit?js,console — no error is thrown.

Comment: `(false ? null : x )` evaluates to `undefined`.

Comment: Yep, I've realised the mistakes I've made.